# Positioning of a JLabel on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm coding a GUI by hand and I've run into difficulty positioning a JLabel on a JPanel. I'm trying to put it in the top left hand side above the JTextField but it's defaulting to the middle even though I'm settings the bounds:

Relevant code:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

JLabel myFleetLabel = new JLabel("My Fleet");
myFleetLabel.setBounds(1,1, 10, 10);

mainPanel.add(myFleetLabel);

add(mainPanel);
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: gui screenshot]

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and maybe [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you might be able achieve this, one might be to use a `GridBagLayout` as the primary layout manager, for example

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            JLabel label = new JLabel("My Fleet: ");
            add(label, gbc);

            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JScrollPane(ta), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5, 10)), gbc);

            JPanel actions = new JPanel();
            actions.add(new JButton("Create Ship"));
            actions.add(new JButton("Flip Coins"));

            gbc.gridy++;
            add(actions, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details.

Remember, it's unlikely that a single layout manager will solve all your problems and some times you will need to use two or more to accomplish the overall effect

Comment: @John Glad it could help

Answer (score 1):

Typically you need to use [layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to place objects in a containter. You should get acquainted with layouts to really code properly in swing.

The being said, the reason your code isn't working as is, is because containers have a layout by default. You **CAN** remove the layout as follows

```
mainPanel.setLayout(null);
```

but this is very bad practice and should be avoided always.

Comment: Downvote explain? I offered documentation to using layouts (the correct way), but also explained why his code wasn't working and how to make it work as is.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but a supporter: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Updated to stress the importance of not using a null layout, but I feel as though showing the one-liner that "fixes" his code is helpful in the process of understanding swing.

Comment: I might recommend and add to your answer the use of [hgap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#setHgap(int)) and [vgap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#setVgap(int)) to add space between components.

Comment: @Frakcool There's a million things to know about layouts, and designing UI in swing. It makes no sense to talk about any of the specifics here (how could you possibly choose which to include and exclude). The resources are all online.

Comment: @Cruncher *"but I feel as though showing the one-liner that "fixes" his code is helpful in the process of understanding swing"* - But `null` layouts don't fix anything, in fact they increase the problems.  Take the time to demonstrate a simplified solution which demonstrates the concepts that the OP will need to learn in order to better solve not only this problem but also other problems in the future and back it up tutorials or other more detailed exampls.  Saying "This is not recommended, but you could do this" does not help the OP or anybody else who might have a similar issue.

Comment: @MadProgrammer OP Is confused why his code isn't behaving as expected. Saying: "Ah, forget about it, just do this. Trust me" isn't answering his concern. And the only way you can explain why his code isn't working is by showing what a null layout is. Clearly the question is about the '.setBounds' lines. And the first line of your answer is "one way to acheive this"

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, I demonstrated *"one way to achieve this"*, I could have used a verity of different layout managers to achieve the same or similar results, but what I did do was show how Swing should be used. `null` layouts are just simply the wrong approach, while there are a few good approaches, each needs to be weighted based on ultimately what the OP wants to achieve

Comment: @Cruncher *"Ah, forget about it, just do this. Trust me"* - Part of that is true, but that is no different from what you are doing.  Sometimes we need to accept, for one reason or another, the OP has chosen the wrong approach to try and solve there problem and help guide them to a the correct approach.  `null` layouts are inherently dangerous, work outside of the prescribed design of the overall API and just cause more trouble for the OP. Personally, I believe that we have a responsibility to provide good advice to posters which provides a professional solution to there problems.

Comment: @Cruncher *OP Is confused why his code isn't behaving as expected*, OP's trying to use a `null` layout. While *maybe* your line of code might solve OP's issue by now, it's not the correct way to solve it. Since in the future he will come back with more and more complex problems derivated from the use of a null layout instead of a layout manager.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm all for telling them the right way to do it! As I did(just didn't write the code like you did, which is very helpful btw). But you can't just turn a blinder to the question.

Comment: @Frakcool nowhere am I advocating use of a null layout. That being said, a question is a question, and this IS the answer. The correct alternative is still there.

Comment: @Cruncher At the end of the day, you are entitled to you opinion, as we are, but you shouldn't get upset when the community as a whole does not condone you approach. Just because something "works" doesn't make it right. If you were teaching some to shoot, would you just teach them how to pull the trigger?  It works, or would you teach them basic principles of gun safety and aiming? Sure your answer will "work", but you've just left the OP to shoot themselves in the foot and the rest of the community to clean up the mess, so forgive us when we get upset out it ;)